# How to decrease Java compilation time in Docker WSL 2?

Tags: java, docker, compilation, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I use Windows, so there is WSL 2 for Docker.
In my project I have docker-compose command that compiles Java code.
Compilation takes over than 15~ minutes. Same situation with Tomcat startup.
I tried to allocate more memory for the WSL in `.wslconfig`(6GB).
It didn't work for me.

How could I decrease compilation time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extreme performance degradation when working with a large number of files, which Java projects often do, in WSL2 is often caused by the files being on the Windows NTFS filesystem (e.g. under `C:\`).  The 9P protocol driver that WSL2 uses to access NTFS is *much* slower than native performance.  See the end of this answer for a comparison on my system.

Is your Java project on the NTFS filesystem?  Or does it live inside the virtual `ext4` filesystem in the WSL2 instance?  If the answer is NTFS, consider the following workarounds:

- Move the project inside the WSL2 instance.  Note that symlinking the project from its existing location to the `ext4` filesystem will not work.
- Usually I'd say "consider WSL1", but that would mean that you would lose Docker.  But you could create a distro in WSL that had the compilation tools needed.  [Reportedly](https://source.coveo.com/2019/10/18/wsl-from-dockerfile/) (I have not done this), you can even `docker export` the container, and then `wsl --import` it into a new instance.  The `wsl --import` command allows you to set `--version 1`.
- Finally, I'm not sure about this one, but you might try Docker Desktop *without* the WSL2 backend.  Using the Hyper-V backed Docker may be faster in this case.

Comparison of `ext4` vs `9P NTFS` under WSL2:

```
~/temp$ time git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel.git
Cloning into 'WSL2-Linux-Kernel'...
...
real    0m40.968s
user    0m8.711s
sys     0m3.795s


/mnt/c$ time git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel.git
Cloning into 'WSL2-Linux-Kernel'...
...
real    8m33.582s
user    0m19.286s
sys     0m42.802s
```

Comment: Yes, I tried the 3d option(switch on Hyper-V. It worked for me fine in performance, but I have got other issues... )